# Xamarin.iOS Framework binding + FastPdfKit

Tags: xamarin

I have a static library (.a) whose include "FastPdfKit.framework". (My Xcode project runs correctly)

This static library is included in xamarin project and i have to bind "FastPdfKit.framework".

So i did: project options -> iOS Build -> Additionnal mtouch arguments (--framework:${ProjectDir}/frameworks/FastPdfKit.framework).

But this mani doesn't run, i've got linked error:

> ld: warning: ignoring file
>   /Users/../Documents/XAMARIN/MyApp.IOS/frameworks/FastPdfKit.framework/FastPdfKit,
>   missing required architecture arm64 in file
>   /Users/../Documents/XAMARIN/MyApp.IOS/frameworks/FastPdfKit.framework/FastPdfKit
>   (2 slices)        Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>           "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFDocumentManager", referenced from:
>               objc-class-ref in MyLib.a(Page.o)
>           "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ReaderViewController", referenced from:
>               objc-class-ref in MyLib.a(Page.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64        clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> MTOUCH: error MT5209: Native linking error: warning: ignoring file
>   /Users/../Documents/XAMARIN/MyApp.IOS/frameworks/FastPdfKit.framework/FastPdfKit,
>   missing required architecture arm64 in file
>   /Users/../Documents/XAMARIN/MyApp.IOS/frameworks/FastPdfKit.framework/FastPdfKit
>   (2 slices) MTOUCH: error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined
>   Objective-C class: MFDocumentManager. The symbol
>   '_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFDocumentManager' could not be found in any of the
>   libraries or frameworks linked with your application. MTOUCH: error
>   MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class:
>   ReaderViewController. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_ReaderViewController'
>   could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with
>   your application. 
>   MTOUCH: error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please
>   review the build log.

Can anyone help me???

Thanks,

Yann

Answer (score 1):

OK, i found.

It was architecture problem. I don't know why because I set architecture option correctly, but not all of architecture setting was generated

Use command line "xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info MyLib.a" to check which architecture is generated.

Answer (score 0):

The error is really very clear, the librarty doesn't support the arm64 architecture as is requested by the project, you need a library compatible with your project's architectures.

Comment: But  I set (in a "FastPdfKit.framework" build setting and in my static library) --> Architectures: $(ARCHS_STANDARD) arm64 armv7 armv7s - $(ARCHS_STANDARD) arm64 armv7 armv7s
--> Valid Architectures: arm64 armv7 armv7s x86_64

Comment: Well, I can't help you beyond this without accessing the project, you must have something wrong in your configuration, did you followed these steps to compile it and make an universal library? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/native_interop/

Comment: Besides to include my "FastPdfKit.framework" with (project options -> iOS Build -> Additionnal mtouch arguments (--framework:${ProjectDir}/frameworks/FastPdfKit.framework).),    I include my lib like that: "project options -> iOS Build -> Additionnal mtouch arguments (--framework:${ProjectDir}/frameworks/FastPdfKit.framework)."

Comment: Follow exactly these steps, from compilation to inclusion and it will work.

Comment: But my library is developed in Obj-C and no native !

Comment: seriously?? Objective-C IS native... do you know what means "native" in this context? (no sarcasm, just asking because I belive you don't speak english)

Comment: So, as I said, Objective-C is native for iOS, so that article is what you exactly must do.